# Selenium with Firefox-Gracefully leaving control to user

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using Atlassian Jira as change tracking tool. I have to enter multiple fields manually and decided to automate. To automate Jira issue creation process, I decided to use Selenium with Firefox 60.0.

When I execute Selenium script, it successfully opens create issue dialog, fills the automateable fields. Then the script stops because there are summary and description fields that user have to manually enter.

I am not calling webdriver.quit() because I want user to continue creation process. However, when the script ends, Jira server connection is closed(I understand this by clicking other buttons and warning comes saying Jira server might be down etc) and create-issue-submit button becomes non-responsive even if I fill all the mandatory fields.

If I automate create-issue-submit button click with filling mandatory fields with placeholder text beforehand, it creates the issue with no problem. But you must understand I will never allow user to automatically create issues, by design decision. I just want to fill empty fields, select options in create-issue-dialog window and leave the rest to user.

I do not see this problem with Internet Explorer 11.0(after script ends, I can click create-issue-submit button and it creates) but its webdriver is buggy, whole script completes in like 30 seconds, get stuck in different part everytime.

I believe the reason is that the company uses Jira certificate that is not recognized. I am not a web developer but I get SEC_UNKNOWN_ISSUER error in Firefox, I believe Firefox is more strict than IE 11. I think Selenium has mechanisms to bypass security measures of Firefox but once the script ends, I am under the regulation of Firefox and it cuts my connection to Jira server. Regardless, I added code piece to trust unknown certificates. Here is the code below;

```
binary = FirefoxBinary(<binary_path>)
profile = FirefoxProfile()
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
driver = Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, firefox_profile=profile)

fill_some_fields()
select_some_options()
```

My workaround for this problem is adding sleep(100) before exiting script. If user clicks create-issue-submit button in 100 seconds, it creates issue. If not, script ends and Jira connection is get lost. But I need a better solution since user might take more than 100 or any arbitrary time delay.

Comment: are you working on a windows PC or on Linux?

Comment: May I suggest that automating the browser interaction may not be the most effective way to accomplish your goal.  Have you investigated configuring your JIRA to properly pre-populate new stories?

Comment: @BreaksSoftware configuring your JIRA to properly pre-populate new stories is a good idea! regarding the automation, Sometimes it's inevitable to do the tasks manually and having automation even on only part of it helps!  Hence my answer...

Comment: @Moshe slavin I am using Windows PC.

Comment: @Breaks Software If you mean using Jira API to submit issues by configuring Jira, it is the thing I exactly do not want to do. I want to prepopulate some fields in the issue creation form and leave control to the user. User will then fill summary and description fields and click Create to finalize. If I want to prepopulate all fields, I will have to create some UI to for user to enter Summary and Description fields, it will need whole another effort.

Comment: Actually, no, I'm suggesting that JIRA project configurations may allow you to set things up so that when a user requests to create a new story for a specific project directly in JIRA, it will pre-populate fields as required.  JIRA is fairly flexible as far as workflow etc. goes.   But this all depends on your business requirements, and the skill level of your JIRA administrator.

Comment: There are two fields in Jira stories that are created with Python and svn commands. I need to extract some svn properties from some local files and look for those properties in xls file etc. If Jira does same thing like reading local xls file and call svn command line functions as easy as python, I might go for it. But I do not prepopulate those fields statically.

Answer (score 2):

This question is very broad... so I'll just try to help with the last problem

> I need a better solution since the user might take more than 100 or any arbitrary time delay

This solution attempts to wait for the users interaction with just adding a confirm button to confirm task was done...

I see you have tried using IE so I guess you are using Windows...

In that case:
If you are just looking for a way to wait for a humans interaction you can use `win32ui`s `MessageBox` with `win32con`s `MB_SYSTEMMODAL` to create a window with a confirm button to confirm the user has done the task the automation could not accomplish...

Her is an example:

```
 import win32ui
 from win32con import MB_SYSTEMMODAL

 start = win32ui.MessageBox("fill empty fields", "Instructions", MB_SYSTEMMODAL)
 if start == 1:
     # do the rest of the automation...
     pass
```

Hope this helps you at least with the user interaction part...

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg you are right! As I mentioned in the answer... "This solution attempts to wait for the users interaction with just adding a confirm button to confirm task was done..." This is not a full answer... Yet I think it does give some direction on human interaction with automation...

Comment: I believe while trying to give proper context, gave too much detail. When script with selenium ends, Jira connection created during automation is closed. Form is prepopulated and still open, but Create button does not respond, because jira connection on webpage is closed. I want to solve this problem, hence the title. Using sleep is just to delay script’s end.

Comment: @MehmetÇağrıKöse I guess the title threw me off: "Gracefully leaving control to user"... Just go with @ BreaksSoftware 's comment...